# C++17 with LSP and Flycheck

Tags: flycheck, lsp-mode, c++

lsp-mode is working correctly.
flyecheck is working correctly, with the exception of regonizing some c++17 features.

```
#include <map>
std::map<int,int> magic;
magic.try_emplace(1,1) // Flycheck does not recognize this code.
```

I have this line on my init.el file:

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook (lambda () (setq flycheck-clang-language-standard "c++17")))
```

I don't know what else to do I have no other problem than this and I'm at a loss for other troubleshooting.

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Hello Drew, if I start emacs with -Q flycheck is not installed nor enabled so there is no issue. But your input is interesting because I can start enabling functionality 1 by 1 and see where this lands me. Thank you!

Comment: No joy, installed the newest clang version for my distro, forced flycheck to use that version and still get the highlight. Maybe will submiit in the flycheck forum.

Comment: Before submitting something, check your flycheck settings with ```C-c ! v``` or ```M-x flycheck-verify-setup``` -it will show what checker is active (should be c/c++-clang), and click on that name, will show you all configuring options. Of particular interest is ```flycheck-clang-include-path``` and ```flycheck-clang-args```. Also please specify the order of execution - starting with only flycheck (if there are errors) then start ```lsp``` then disconnect lsp.

Comment: @Ian so when I run the verify setup it shows that the first checker to run is lsp and checkers that could run if selected is clang and gcc and cppcheck. If I manually change to clang as first checker to run it solves the issue. so the problem is that it's running lsp on the wrong server

Comment: So `M-x flycheck-verify-setup`is the right answer @Ian